# MEAN compile automatically on source file changes

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I'm trying to "run and autocompile" a mean server whit Angular4 . 
I launch server with this command:

```
ng build && node server.js
```

which start correctly the express server, but! Every time I make a change on source file it does not compile automatically as this command do(ofc only Angular2)

```
ng serve
```

Well I know that ng serve only compile and start Angular2 server but it removes dist folder too !

I followed this tutorial for my server:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

Thank you!

Andrea

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I solved the problem.

ng serve delete the dist folder on root -> node server.js search it and it fails.

the solution is: run 2 console.

the first is for

```
ng build --watch
```

process, which look for changes and recompile it,

the second is

```
node server.js
```

Andrea

Comment: You save my day!! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

ng build is for bundle, it is meant to be pre-compiled.
ng serve is for development process, which mean that ng serve create an instance of local development server that monitor your file changes and perform any update for any changes that you've done. So to put it shortly, what you see is working by design or it's intended to do so thus if you want to develop run ng serve; but for production run ng build